# Extending TabViewStyle styleData

Tags: qt, qt-quick, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I am currently trying to find a nicer way to do this, add an icon to a tab. Right now I am piggy backing off the styleData.title to include the icon source, but it would be nice to be able to extend the styleData so I can include other custom properties.

Here is my current hack:

```
Tab {
    ...
    title: "Home|images/home-75.png"
    ...
}

style: TabViewStyle {
    ...
    tab: Rectangle {
        ...
        Text {
            ...
            text: styleData.title.split("|")[0]
            ...
        }
        Image {
            ...
            source: styleData.title.split("|")[1]
        }
    }
}
```

However it would be much nicer to just do this:

```
Tab {
    ...
    title: "Home"
    source: "images/home-75.png"
    ...
}

style: TabViewStyle {
    ...
    tab: Rectangle {
        ...
        Text {
            ...
            text: styleData.title
            ...
        }
        Image {
            ...
            source: styleData.source
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the application markup as is:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 480

    TabView {
        id: tabwidget
        x: 0
        y: 0
        tabPosition: Qt.BottomEdge
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        Tab {
            id: homeTab
            title: "Home|images/home-75.png"
            source: "images/home-75.png"
            component: Qt.createComponent("Page2.qml")
        }

        Tab {
            id: inboxTab
            title: "Inbox|images/home-75.png"
            component: Qt.createComponent("Page3.qml")
        }

        Tab {
            id: outboxTab
            title: "Outbox"
            source: "images/home-75.png"
            component: Qt.createComponent("Page3.qml")
        }

        Tab {
            id: settingTab
            title: "Settings"
            source: "images/home-75.png"
            component: Qt.createComponent("Page3.qml")
        }

        style: TabViewStyle {
            frameOverlap: 0
            tab: Rectangle {
                color: "#F6F6F7"
                border.width: 0
                implicitWidth: (parent.control.width + 3) / 4
                implicitHeight: 88
                radius: 0
                CustomBorder
                {
                    commonBorder: false
                    lBorderwidth: 0
                    rBorderwidth: 0
                    tBorderwidth: 1
                    bBorderwidth: 0
                    borderColor: "#bababc"
                }
                Text {
                    id: text
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    text: styleData.title.split("|")[0]
                    color: styleData.selected ? "#ff3b30" : "#8e8e8f"
                }
                Image {
                    id: img
                    width: 75
                    height: 75
                    source: styleData.title.split("|")[1]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create component `IconTab.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Tab {
    property url iconSource
}
```

Then replace all your `Tab`s width `IconTab`s, e.g.

```
IconTab {
    id: outboxTab
    title: "Outbox"
    iconSource: "images/home-75.png"
}
```

And get the icon's source in the TabViewStyle via:

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log("title: " + styleData.title)
    console.log("title: " + tabwidget.getTab(styleData.index).title)
    console.log("icon: " + tabwidget.getTab(styleData.index).iconSource)
}
```

Btw. check out the documentation for [Tab.source](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#source-prop)  and [Tab.sourceComponent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#sourceComponent-prop). Tab.component should not work. At least, it is not documented.

Comment: You have "MyTab.qml" thus it should be "MyTab {", not "IconTab {". Works perfect though thanks!

Comment: I am doing the same thing but getting : Unable to assign [undefined] to QUrl